# What is the difference in python between using z = x + y, and z = f"{x}{y}"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I am a beginner at python 3 and have recently taken it up to pass the time productively. I am inquiring on what the difference is between these two statements, `z = x + y`, `z = f"{x}{y}"` . They both produce the same output, so I am wondering why the python book I am reading is advising to use the more complex code rather than just z = x + y. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What book, and what exactly does it say?

Comment: The format string works for any type, not just strings.

Comment: If `x` is 2 and `y` is 3, the first will yield 5 and the second will yield "23".  You can only use the first equation for string concatenation if you know both items are strings.  The second works for any type of object.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Teach me this basic language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a _specific_ question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f-strings are useful because they make templates more readable than concatenation. For example, take these two equivalent programs.

```py
print("Hello, " + name + "! Rooms " + str(x) + " and " + str(y) + " are ready.")
```

```py
print(f"Hello, {name}! Rooms {x} and {y} are ready.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this scenario, z=x+y looks simpler. But say you want to greet a user with a string:

name = "Mike"

balance = "10000"

```
greeting = "Hello, "+ name + "your balance is: "+balance +' !'
```

**vs**

```
greeting = f"Hello, {name} your balance is: {balance}!"
```

That second version looks a lot cleaner and you are less likely to miss a space or comma as you can see the entire string as you *format* it